# Facebook not showing proper thumbnail of app image

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I built an app, the Facebook however does not shows the thumbnail completely. It just crops the image everytime. I have tried with various image sizes but still no success.The open graph data is also included and Fb OG Debugger does not show any error.

A sample page :
https://soumou.website/apps/share.php?img=1770489253166485_20160918092759&sex=male&name=Sourav+Ghosh&app=partner_thinks

[image: How the image appears]

[image: The actual image]

Answer (score -1):

Well, that's Facebook. It stretches the image proportionally and that's why it's cropping.

Workaround: attach an image itself in the post. Save image as... > save it > click Photo/Video when posting

Comment: sorry cant get your answer. how to attach  ?

Comment: @Sourav RMB > Save image as... > save it > click Photo/Video when posting